# My split view controller is making the window really thin

Tags: xcode, macos

I just started learning about all this Xcode stuff earlier today, so this might be a stupid question.

Basically, I have a split view controller and one of it's views has a text view in it (I'm trying to make a basic text-editor). The problem is, when I run it, the window's really thin - like 20px wide. Here's an image of my storyboard:

[image]

And here's the actual app:

[image]

If I resize the window manually by dragging the side, it works perfectly, also, if I *don't* use a split view controller and instead use a *normal* view controller it also works perfectly without me having to resize it myself.

Comment: You may need to implement the min and max size for the views in the Split View

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any option for the min and max size - just the normal width and height which is set to 450x300 for each

Comment: Check NSSplitViewDelegate

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using Objective-C or Swift? You need to look into Protocols and Delegates.

Comment: I'm using swift. What're protocols and delegates?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have to put content in your split views.
For exemple, put a button in the middle of both split views and set their constrains. Then everything will be good.